# How to determine complexity of JS recursive functions?

Tags: javascript, recursion, big-o

I have code1

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
function sumTo(n) {
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return n + sumTo(n - 1);
}

console.log(sumTo(100));
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
```

and code2

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
function sumTo(n) {
  return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}

console.log(sumTo(100));
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
```

First code shows

```
5050
Execution time: 6
```

Second

```
5050
Execution time: 7
```

As I understand,code1 is linear,so O(n) and code2 is O(2^n).
Why is execution time difference so small?

Comment: the Big O of code 2 is `O(1)`. It always run in linear time as it has no recursion, the first is `O(n)`

Comment: 6-7 milliseconds is way too short time to make any conclusions, you're basically measuring warmup time and noise. You need to do something like `for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { sumTo(100); }` to get the execution time to *at least* 1 second.

Comment: i am not sure how you will reach n2 with suming numbers, this is a bad example

Comment: @Liam I can sum 5000,for 50000 I got max stack trace problem.

Comment: why are you even doing this? Code1 is obviously going to be considerably more efficient. This all seems very contrived and pointless. Yes you will max out the stack...which is just another reason why you shouldn't do this, like ever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arithmetic calculations does not contribute to complexity, code 1 is O(n) code 2 is O(1)

and your test is not enough try sumTo(10000000000000000000)

[Read the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)